# Blackjack game: Determining the winner

Tags: python, oop, blackjack

I made a blackjack game which works entirely except for determining the winner. Could anyone help me on what I am doing wrong? Here's an example on what happens when I run the program.

```
Cooper 's cards are : Five of Spades and King of Hearts
The Dealer's cards are: Eight of Diamonds and Ten of Spades
Your total is 15, Would you like to take a hit or stay? hit
You drew a Eight of Hearts .
You now have a total of 23
You busted!
You beat the Dealer! You got lucky punk.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It says I busted, but then say I won.

Also if you guys know anyway I could clean this up let me know!

```
from Deck import Deck
from Card import Card
from Hand import Hand
import sys

deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()

def rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal):
    if int(playerTotal) > 21:
        print "You busted!"
        if int(dealerTotal) == 21:
            print 'To make it worse, dealer has 21.'
    if int(dealerTotal) > 21:
        print "The Dealer has busted. You win!"
    if int(playerTotal) == 21:
        print " You got 21! So you win!"
        if int(dealerTotal) == 21:
            print "The Dealer also got 21. Tough Break."
    elif int(dealerTotal) == 21:
        print "The Dealer got 21! Tough Break, you lose!"
    else:
        if int(playerTotal) > int(dealerTotal):
            print "You beat the Dealer! You got lucky punk."
        elif int(playerTotal) == int(dealerTotal):
            print "It is a push, no one wins!"
        elif int(playerTotal) < int(dealerTotal):
            print "Dealer wins! Better luck next time loser."

def game():

    player = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    print "        /////////////////////////////////////////\n" \
          "       /////////////////////////////////////////\n" \
          "      ///////// LET'S PLAY BLACKJACK //////////\n" \
          "     /////////////////////////////////////////\n" \
          "    /////////////////////////////////////////\n"
    pCard1 = deck.deal()
    pCard2 = deck.deal()
    print player, "'s cards are :", pCard1, "and", pCard2
    dCard1 = deck.deal()
    dCard2 = deck.deal()
    print "The Dealer's cards are:", dCard1, "and", dCard2
    playerTotal = (Card.getCardValue(pCard1) + Card.getCardValue(pCard2))
    dealerTotal = (Card.getCardValue(dCard1) + Card.getCardValue(dCard2))
    if playerTotal == 21:
        rules(playerTotal,dealerTotal)
    elif dealerTotal == 21:
        rules(playerTotal,dealerTotal)
    else:
        option = raw_input("Your total is " + str(playerTotal) + ", Would you like to take a hit or stay? ")
        if option == "Hit" or option == "hit":
            pCard = deck.deal()
            playerTotal = playerTotal + (Card.getCardValue(pCard))
            print "You drew a", pCard, "."
            print "You now have a total of", playerTotal
            while playerTotal < 21:
                option = raw_input("Your total is " + str(playerTotal) + ", Would you like to take a hit or stay? ")
                if option == "stay" or option == "Stay":
                    dealersTurn(dealerTotal)
                    dealerHit(playerTotal,dealerTotal)
                    rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal)
                else:
                    pCard = deck.deal()
                    playerTotal = playerTotal + (Card.getCardValue(pCard))
                    print "You drew a", pCard, "."
                    print "You now have a total of", playerTotal
            rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal)
            sys.exit
        if option == "stay" or option == "Stay":
            dealersTurn(dealerTotal)
            dealerHit(playerTotal,dealerTotal)
            rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal)



def dealerHit(playerTotal,dealerTotal):
    while dealerTotal < playerTotal:
        dcard = deck.deal()
        dealerTotal = dealerTotal + (Card.getCardValue(dcard))
        print "The dealer drew a", dcard, "."
        print "The dealer now has a total of", dealerTotal
    return dealerTotal



def dealersTurn(dealerTotal):
    while dealerTotal < 17:
        dcard = deck.deal()
        dealerTotal = dealerTotal + (Card.getCardValue(dcard))
    return dealerTotal




game()
```

Comment: Follow the logic.. What happens after printing "You busted"? Note the difference between `if` and `elif`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal):
    if int(playerTotal) > 21:
        print "You busted!"
        if int(dealerTotal) == 21:
            print 'To make it worse, dealer has 21.'
        print "Dealer wins! Better luck next time loser."
        return

    if int(dealerTotal) > 21:
        print "The Dealer has busted. You win!"
        return

    if int(playerTotal) == 21:
        print " You got 21! So you win!"
        if int(dealerTotal) == 21:
            print "The Dealer also got 21. Tough Break."
        return
    elif int(dealerTotal) == 21:
        print "The Dealer got 21! Tough Break, you lose!"
        return
    else:
        if int(playerTotal) > int(dealerTotal):
            print "You beat the Dealer! You got lucky punk."
        elif int(playerTotal) == int(dealerTotal):
            print "It is a push, no one wins!"
        elif int(playerTotal) < int(dealerTotal):
            print "Dealer wins! Better luck next time loser."
    return
```

Many logic problems. I don't know if I caught them all.

Comment: This works but whenever I hit, then I stay this happens. `The dealer drew a Eight of Spades .
The dealer now has a total of 22
You beat the Dealer! You got lucky punk.
Your total is 18, Would you like to take a hit or stay? stay
The dealer drew a Queen of Clubs .
The dealer now has a total of 24
You beat the Dealer! You got lucky punk.
Your total is 18, Would you like to take a hit or stay? hit
You drew a Seven of Clubs .
You now have a total of 25
You busted!
Dealer wins! Better luck next time loser.`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `print` to a `return` in the `rules` method it will do what you expect. You want as soon as one check is true, not to bother checking other conditions.

However, before you call the method in your main `game` method, you are already doing some checks:

```
if playerTotal == 21:
    rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal)
```

If the player has hit 21, you don't need to check the rules because the player wins; similarly you have:

```
elif dealerTotal == 21:
    rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal)
```

again, if the dealer hits 21, the house wins - there is no need for a specific check.

You need to remove this check, and whenever the cards are dealt - you need to do the calculations with the `rules` method; or quite simply, keep playing the game until either the player hits 21 or above, or the house (dealer) hits 21 or above:

```
 player_total = Card.getCardValue(pCard1) + Card.getCardValue(pCard2)
 dealer_total = Card.getCardValue(dCard1) + Card.getCardValue(dCard2)

 while player_total <= 21 or dealer_total <= 21:
    # Your game logic
    player_total += Card.getCardValue(pCard1) + Card.getCardValue(pCard2)
    dealer_total += Card.getCardValue(dCard1) + Card.getCardValue(dCard2)

 if player_total == 21:
     print('You win')
 else:
     print('You lose')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just one more question how would make it so the game replays after I get the winner? Thanks

Comment: You'd have to have an outer control loop, that simply calls the dealer logic loop after the game is over. Something like `continue_game = raw_input('Do you want to continue? '); if continue_game[0].upper() == 'Y': start_game()` where `start_game()` is your dealer method.

Answer (score 0):

Taesu's answer is close, but it simply isn't possible to correctly play a blackjack hand by playing the two hands first and then looking at the totals afterwards, as you do here. Play of the hand and result of the hand are intertwined, and must be put into the same function, which does all of the following, in order:

1. deal two cards to dealer and player.
2. if dealer's upcard is ace, offer insurance bet (you might want
   to eliminate this for simplicity)
3. if upcard is ace or ten, dealer peeks. If he has natural, game is
   over. players with natural tie, others lose.
4. pay/take the insurance bet.
5. dealer was not natural, so if player has natural, pay bonus
   (3/2, 6/5, whatever you've decided) game over.
6. allow player to hit: this is a loop. If he busts, break out of
   the loop and game over, player loses. you may want to leave
   out things like doubling and splitting for simplicity.
7. player ended loop by standing, so now play dealer's hand by
   appropriate rules. If dealer busts, game over, player wins.
8. finally, if neither busts, then equal hand push, greater wins.